# Should migrations not have seed data in them when pushed to production ? EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database, .net-5

I'm using C#, ASP.NET Core / .NET 5.0 API, EF Core ( last version ) and Azure SQL Database for production.

**The problem:**

I added seed data in my first migration `InitialCreate` using `Entity<T>.HasData()` and then pushed it to the Azure DB. Everything worked and then I tried adding a new entity as well as modifying one and left the seed data the way it was.
What I got in the migration file was a lot of `Delete` and the same amount of `Added` and it was because of some seed data had `Id = Guid.NewGuid()` so it was deleting them and adding them again etc. and it was very confusing.

**The question:**

**My question is should migrations not have seed data in them when pushed to production in order to not have mistakes in the migrations files when publishing ?**

When I commented all the seed data and ran a second migration what I got was a huge migration file deleting all the previously added seed data from the first migration and I was even more confused.

Basically it feels like for every migrations it runs the seed data again but **should I just delete all the seed data when I'm ready to publish ?** I had data in my Azure DB that I had to delete because of the mistakes I made in the migration files and I want to not having to delete any live data anymore because of publishing mistakes.

Also, **is seed data just for testing or could it be used for starting the system with data already in it like I'd like to do ?** I just don't want to have it create problem for my new migrations ( I'm pretty new to migrations, I've read the docs and watched courses about it on Pluralsight but nothing answered my questions )

Comment: Protip: EF Migrations don’t scale, nor do they really work with any kind of non-trivial DB design changes. Eventually you’ll have to start writing them by hand. Without seeing your actual DB design changes we cannot say for certain, but from here I’ll say _it’s possible_ that your project has past that point.

Comment: What, none of your tables have initial data necessary for the system to function?

Comment: @Dai that's the part where they were saying "Modify migration file" in the docs then, ok because I thought migration files where the sacred files you should not touch and instead make your code more obvious and generate the file again. So it is good practice to modify them at will right ?

Comment: @CaiusJard yes they do but this confuses me so much I don't know if I was doing it right maybe it wasn't the way to go about it you know

Comment: For initial data I seed using known IDs

Comment: @CaiusJard exactly, I've read the docs and they said it needs known IDs otherwise it will recreate them etc, but my question is when I'm going to create a new migration, it won't conflict with anything since it won't run the seed data again since it has known IDs right ? Should I leave the seed data uncommented and leave it alone ?

Comment: EF knows it has run a particular migration; in the DB you will find a table called __EFMigrationsHistory which records the name of run migrations. This is used to work out which shall be run